# Compare two URL-s with or without www in PHP

Tags: php, url, subdomain

I have Iframe that inserts data into my DB from another websites using $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] value.

One of the  column inserted is website URL that can start with

***www*** (e.g: www.viber.ge) or without it (just viber.ge).

I need to compare URL that Iframe has already inserted into DB to URL that Iframe is on at the moment.

But there can be ***www as subdomain name***

So how can I be sure starting ***www*** is subdomain or not?
(I putted hello at the top but it is not showing up -_- )

**Question is not about comparing "www.viber.ge" with "viber.ge"**

**it is more about comparing "www.www.viber.ge"(which I think can be inserted into the DB as "www.viber.ge")**

**with www.viber.ge (which I think can be inserted into DB as "viber.ge" or "www.viber.ge").**

Additional question:

is it possible user to go to "www.www.viber.ge" and $_SERVER to save it as "www.viber.ge" (subdomain)?

Comment: what about `contact.viber.ge`?

Comment: I can handle those, I'm stuck at www. I was going to remove starting "www." from both URL-s but it can be subdomain name -_-

Comment: you can try using a regex in your sql query

Comment: @JoshKisb I have website url-s in my DB like "www.viber.ge" or "viber.ge", so if anyone creates subdomain "www.viber.ge" (so it would be "www.www.viber.ge") it could anyways be inserted in my db as "www.viber.ge" (Subdomain), So I wonder is there a way to differ those two? Or can I do something at the point when I am inserting those URl-s into my DB to then differ them

Comment: well its not clear whether you actually allow www subdomain when domain already exist. your logic should be more straightforward

Comment: @JoshKisb Sure, but I want to handle all of the possibilities.

Comment: Maybe to help us humans better understand you could edit your question to include some scenarios with input and expected output.

Comment: Ok, Close the question or whatever, I can not explain it easier to humans.

Answer (score 2):

You can use str_replace and remove the shorter url from the longer.
If what is left is "www." Only then it's the same domain.

```
$url1 = "www.viber.ge";
$url2 = "viber.ge";

If(strlen($url1) > strlen($url2)){
    If(str_replace($url2,"",$url1) == "www."){
        Echo "same domain";
    }Else{
        Echo "not same";
    }
}Else{
    If(str_replace($url1,"",$url2) == "www."){
        Echo "same domain";
    }Else{
        Echo "not same";
    }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/XtHWr

Comment: I think I was not clear about my question. What about www as subdomain name? If there is www.www.viber.ge that my Iframe inserted in to DB as www.viber.ge (which is subdomain)? Or is that actually possible? If, lets say, there is "www.www.viber.ge" accessing website like www.viber.ge would go to "viber.ge" and not subdomain because to go to the subdomain user actually had to go to "www.www.viber.ge" which would be inserted into db as is. One way it would not be inserted in that way would be server to redirect to page without "www" which would result to going on just viber.ge without subdomain?

Comment: I think I messed up that comment a little bit but there is some logic. So there goes another question, is it possible user to go to "www.www.viber.ge" and $_SERVER to save it as "www.viber.ge" (subdomain)?

Comment: I'm really confused what you want. You first talk about without www and with www. Now it's about www.www and www.  Make up your mind and edit your post in a **clear** way.

Comment: It was all about subdomain (as "www") from the beginning. I know how to compare two  strings. I wrote "But there can be www as subdomain name

So how can I be sure starting www is subdomain or not?". That should **clear** that up :)

Comment: No, I still don't get it. And as far as I can see nobody else does either since you don't get any other answers. Again **edit your post/question** in a clear way.

Comment: What is there to get, there can be www as subdomain name right? So when I insert that URL into my DB how can I be sure that www. is about subdomain or it is just ordinary "www.". Read the question I don't know clearer way to explain It. You don't understanding it doesn't mean nobody can, mate. Question doesn't deserve -1 cause I could not find similar question anywhere But I don't care about points here I want an answer that you simply can not give.